# Share download link for alfresco documents

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

is it possible to share download link for a document hosted in alfresco?

Just like copying the share link of a document, the idea is to make the user can copy download link for (an already shared document) and share it with anyone.

please any solution for that would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to create public url of document?

Answer (score 0):

Alfreso has Share facility for sharing document url for public use.
When you open that url,it is already providing download link.
Check below Image:
[image]

[image]